# Select random field from database in Python

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, random

So I am developing a Django app and what I want at the moment in to develop a script that selects a random field from a row with 3 words in a MySQL database that I have. I have searched for info but haven't managed how to do it.

My database:

[image]

What I want is the script to read the database and select a random word each time. I haven't worked so much with DBs in Python so I have no clue about how to do it. Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `random.choice` like this:

```
import random

columns = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3']
chosen_column = random.choice(columns)

#now access DB using chosen_column for example:
Your_model.objects.raw('SELECT ' + chosen_column + ' FROM myapp_yourmodel')
```

Comment: Okay thanks, when you mean access the DB using chosen_column what do you mean? Do I have to create a connexion with the MySQL database first?

Comment: If you're using Django, you probably can use the model so you don't have to specifically create a connection. I'll edit my answer with an example

Comment: Wouldn't it be smarter to `choice()` after getting the data?

Comment: I imagine I'll have to do that in the view I'm rendering, don't I? @Gamopo

Comment: Sure! Or wherever you want to use it

Comment: I would suggest .values() instead of .raw()